# Django choicefield change affect charfield value

Tags: python, html, django, choicefield

I am new with Django and I am trying to change dynamically the value of a charfield according to the change of the choicefield.

For example if the choicefield is displaying "A", I want that the charfield containts the value "Anaconda", and if I change the choicefield to the "B" value, I want the charfield to show "Boa".

Is there any way to do this with Django ?

Thank you.

Comment: You will need to use some JavaScript.

Comment: Ok thank you, i will check this later.